# Divide num by (num / 10) recursively

Tags: recursion

I'm trying to write a function that divides a number by his tens recursively.
For ex: Given the number 555, the function will return **2**:
555 / 55 / 5 = 2

The following code outputs **11**:
555 / (55 / 5) = 50

```js
function recursion(num){
    return num < 10 ? num : Math.floor(num / recursion(Math.floor(num / 10)));
}

console.log(recursion(555));
```

How should the desired function to be programmed recursively yet conventionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using a recursive multiplication function as follows:

```js
function divideByTens(num){
    return Math.floor(num / recursionM(Math.floor(num / 10)));
}

function recursionM(num){
    if(num < 10)
        return num;

    return num * recursionM(Math.floor(num / 10));
}

console.log(divideByTens(555));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
function int recursion(int num) {

    var count = 0;
    var remainder = num/10;

    if remainder > 0 {

        count = recursion(remainder);
        count += 1;
    }

    return count;
}

recursion(5555);
```